# Are variables created automatically for expressions in Javascript when used without assignment?

Tags: javascript, variables, compiler-optimization

For example in the following code:

```js
const productIds = [123, 100, 50];
const test1 = () => productIds.sort(); // *

if (100 === productIds.sort()[0]) { // **
  console.log('equal!');
}
```

In example `*` a sorted array is returned. But I assume before it's returned it must be sorted and the result saved somewhere. Does Javascript compiler create a variable automatically in the function scope?

Same goes in example `**` where an expression `test1.sort()[0]` is evaluated based on equality with `100`.

If a variable is still created in local scope then I could as well declare it manually and possibly it would be beneficial in terms of code readability.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. `sort` sorts arrays _in-place_, so no new variable is necessary. Even if it sorted out-of-place, no new variable would be necessary as `products.sort()` is an expression that resolves to a value. `test1.sort` doesn’t make sense; `test1` is a function, not an array. How would you declare a variable manually? Can you give an example of what your alternative code would look like?

Comment: Question is unclear , anyway trying to understand by your question If we are sorting the data i.e (*) where will be unsorted array, is these the question your trying to ask?

Comment: Did you mean `productIds` instead of `products` and `test1()` instead of `test1`?

Comment: @Bergi yes corrected this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Javascript compiler create a variable automatically in the function scope?

No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter stores temporary values (that come up during the evaluation of expressions) in memory, yes, but it does not create variables in a scope for them.